# Java Banker's algorithm, finding safe sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

For a homework assignment, I am tasked with implementing the Banker's algorithm in Java.

I am trying to write a function that will determine if a request for resources (passed as a parameter) will lead to a safe state, and therefore, acceptable or not.

So for each request, I simulate having accepted it, by adding to that requesting thread's resource total, and taking away that much from the bank's resources.

In order to determine if I am at a safe state, I iterate through the other threads and I check to see if I can theoretically give them enough resources to finish, and after they "finish", I take back their resources to the bank, and move on to the next resource to see if I can't take care of it as well. If i cannot, I skip it and check the next one after which I might revisit the last. Eventually I will have a sequence with which I can grant the resources I have correctly.

So say I have threads: 0 1 2 3 4
but a safe sequence may be something like 4 3 2 1 (worst case)

**What kind of data structure can I use that will allow me to constantly iterate until I am sure there is at least one safe sequence?**

It would work something like this:

Iteration1: 0 1 2 3x 4

Iteration2: 0 1x 2 4

Iteration3: 0x 2 4

Iteration4: 2x 4

Iteration5: 4x

So safe Sequence is: 3, 1, 0, 2, 4
So as I am iterating, the set is getting smaller as I am "ejecting" one of the processes each time because I know it's safe for the algo to choose that one next.

Comment: Why can't you just use a 2d array?

Comment: because once I have iterated through it once, I am done.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework problem, I guessing that you're supposed to work this out on your own.

However, Dijkstra's algorithm is very well documented in a number of places, including the data structures used.

If you have specific questions about specific data structure implementations in Java, and whether they are well-suited to a particular task, I'm sure there are lots of folks here willing to help.

Comment: Yes, I understand the algorithm perfectly. I could have asked the question without even mentioning it, but I thought it would be easier for someone to visualize. What I need help with is choosing a data structure to do this.